# JSoup - get href

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have this html code, and I need to get the link

```
<div class="squaresContent narrow">
  <input type="hidden" id="category_path" value="1_Komputery > Części i obudowy komputerowe > Dyski twarde" />
  <div class="productItem  first2Col first3Col first4Col first">
    <a class="productItemContent withNames  productsView" href='http://www.okazje.info.pl/km/komputery/samsung-ssd-850-evo-250gb-sata3-2-5-mz-75e250b-eu.html'>
```

I do next :

```
String ref = null;
for (Element el : doc.getElementsByClass("squaresContent narrow")) {
    for (Element elem : el.getElementsByClass("productItem  first2Col first3Col first4Col first")
            .select("a")) {
        ref = elem.attr("abs:href");
    }
}
```

But it`s not work.
What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementsByClass` should be used only with ONE class name as argument. If you need multiple class names you can use the css selector syntax, where a class name is specified by `.classname`, i.e. dot followed by the class name:

```
String ref = null;
for (Element el : doc.select(".squaresContent.narrow")) {
  for (Element elem : el.select(".productItem.first2Col.first3Col.first4Col.first a")) {
    ref = elem.attr("abs:href");
  }
}
```

BTW: your loops run not very efficiently. In the case when more then one matching element is found in the outer or inner loop you overwrite the ref variable. A more elegant way of doing this might be:

```
String ref = null;
try{
    Element aEl = doc.select(".squaresContent.narrow").last()
          .select(".productItem.first2Col.first3Col.first4Col.first a").last();
    ref = aEl.attr("abs:href");
}
catch (NullPointerException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You need the try catch because there might not be any matching a element and this results in a NPE.